# Screen Resolution ( C# Win 8.1 app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm developing an App for windows 8.1 and i need to get the resolution of the device screen.

I searched the forum and find:

```
Window.Current.Bounds.Width
Window.Current.Bounds.Height
```

But this returns only the resolution of the app window.

Comment: It returns the size of the window.  Resolution is something else.  And an important reason you shouldn't care about the screen size.  [Read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know it returns the size of the window. This is exactly the problem, because i need the size of the device screen where the application is running. I had read the text, but thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you should use the screen class

```
> Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
> 
> int S_width=screen.Bounds.Width;
> 
> int S_height=screen.Bounds.Height;
```

as indicated several places on stackoverflow